jellyfin for kodi not loading library on xbox
i am trying to make jellyfin for kodi work on xbox (latest version pulled from your repo.)  i can read the jellyfin library from the video add-on, and also in dlna, but it never populates kodi's library.  when i boot the app the add-on welcomes me, asks which mode i want to use (add-on), and then asks which libraries i want to copy over.  the only option it gives me is All.  i have one library called videos and never asks me specifically about that.  i have no evidence it's doing anything after i select All.  the library is 10TB so i'd understand if it were slow, but i really don't think it's doing anything at all.  anyone else having success?  thoughts?

What kind of app are you running?

its kodi for xbox.  it's a media client interacting with my media server, jellyfin, via this plugin.
